# Send time_t datatype by function MPI_send()

Tags: c++, mpi

I need to `MPI_Send()` variable `fileChangedTime`.

```
    struct stat fileinfo;        
    string name = "foo.txt";

    time_t fileChangedTime = 0;
    if(-1 != stat(name.c_str(), &fileinfo)){
        fileChangedTime = fileinfo.st_mtime;
    }
```

I'm not sure about the conversion of time_t to MPI datatype. T.

Comment: Don't tag with a language you are obviouslyy not using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `MPI_Send` you can transfer any data. `MPI_Datatype` field simply specify size of each element of data pointed by `void*` as first argument.

```
typedef struct {
  int   a;
  float b;
} my_t;
...
my_t m;
int error = MPI_Send((void*)&m, // data
                     sizeof(t), // size in of data in bytes
                     MPI_CHAR,  // or use MPI_BYTE or MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR
                     0, 0, comm);
```

So with above example you can send any data by specifying size of it in bytes and some type with 1 byte size. In you case like this

```
int error = MPI_Send((void*)&fileChangedTime,  // data
                     sizeof(fileChangedTime),  // size in of data in bytes
                     MPI_BYTE,                 // or use MPI_BYTE or MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR
                     0, 0, comm);
```